# How to set the config in OpenCart?

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

> Warning: require_once(/sgweb1/minufashion/system/startup.php)
>   [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   D:\inetpub\vhosts\sgwebgene.com\httpdocs\minufashion\index.php on line
>   15
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required '/sgweb1/minufashion/system/startup.php'
>   (include_path='.;./includes;./pear') in
>   D:\inetpub\vhosts\sgwebgene.com\httpdocs\minufashion\index.php on line
>   15

I am hosting to the server then the error is showing.

Comment: Have you found the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 6):

Notice path discrepancy:

```
sgwebgene.com\httpdocs\minufashion\index.php
```

and

```
/sgweb1/minufashion/system/startup.php
```

Did you change your folders after deploying opencart?

In `config.php` there are lines like these:

```
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/xxxx/public_html/shop/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/xxxx/public_html/shop/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', '/home/xxxx/public_html/shop/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/xxxx/public_html/shop/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/xxxx/public_html/shop/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/xxxx/public_html/shop/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/xxxx/public_html/shop/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/xxxx/public_html/shop/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/xxxx/public_html/shop/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/xxxx/public_html/shop/system/logs/');
```

Make sure those are proper for your setup