# getting error while uploading on server using web application opencart

Tags: opencart

I need a help on this problem. I uploaded my site using web application, I am using opencart. This is my first time that I encounter this problem. My website is http://www.almadina-adv.com. I cannot solve it.

Error found:

> Warning: require_once(/home/almadina-adv/public_html/system/startup.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in /home/mohamedb/public_html/index.php on line 19
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/almadina-adv/public_html/system/startup.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/mohamedb/public_html/index.php on line 19

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup the config files to point to the right place on the server rather than on your development machine:

```
/admin/config.php
/config.php
```

This post has more details on [how to setup the opencart config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860150/how-to-set-the-config-in-opencart)